# Как определить на сервере общее количество элементов?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

Вообщем когда у меня на сервере выполняется пагинация то в ответе сервер должен включать так же общее количество элементов в целом (без всплывающей) коллекции. Как это можно сделать? Для пагинации использую kaminari и api-pagination

```
class PostsController < ApplicationController

  def index
    posts = paginate Post.all, per_page: 10 
    render json: JSON.pretty_generate(posts.as_json)
  end

end
```

Answer (score 0):

Вы можете добавить дополнительный объект meta в ваш json и в нём передать всё, что хотите.

```
def index
  posts = paginate Post.all, per_page: 10 
  render json: JSON.pretty_generate(posts.as_json),
         meta: { total: posts.count }
end
```